# Running a McNemar test on all combinations of data

Tags: r, chi-squared

I'm looking to run a McNemar test on a frame of data. The frame is set up as follows (valueToThrow are values that are irrelevant and that I don't want in the final output):

```
importantDescriptor1,importantDescriptor2,valueToThrow1,valueToThrow2,McNemarValue
```

This is one row of the data, and there are ~10000 lines to this frame. For each row, I want to run a McNemar test on all of the combinations of McNemarValue items in the frame in relation to the current row, while making an identifier out of a combination of the two rows that were used to create the McNemar statistic. For example,

```
(Header Line) combinationOfDescriptor1,combinationOfDescriptor2,chiSquaredValue
ABX vs ABY, XYZ vs ZYX, 22
ACX vs ADY, XRZ vs AYX, 41
ABC vs EBY, XYT vs ZYS, 2
```

For the test itself, I'll be using the formula (CR)^2 = ( D - A ) / sqrt( D + A ). Is there any way to compare all of these values, and then output them to either a file or another data frame (which could then be outputted to a file)?

To further elaborate, this is the equivalent pseudocode that I want to apply:

```
for i in len(frame){ //runs until i = len(frame)
    j=i+1
    for j in len(frame){ //runs until j=len(frame)
        pull data from i line
        pull data from j line
        McNemarTest(dataFromi,dataFromj)
        add to output
    }
}
```

Comment: See `?Control`,  `?seq`, `?\`[data.frame\``, and `?c`

Comment: Are you able to elaborate further? Providing four function calls and their man pages isn't super helpful if you don't express how to use those items.

Comment: Your question appears to be about very basic concepts of control flow, accessing elements from a dataframe and storing results of calculation in a data structure, such as a vector. These concepts are well addressed in the man pages and any basic tutorial on R. Learning to use those recourses would be more useful to you than my answering this question...